# I'm trying to access a postgres db remotely, but the postgres service won't start after modifying pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf

Tags: postgresql, remote-access, postgresql-9.5

I have read that in order to enable remote access to a postgres db, one must modify pg_hba.conf to add a Client Authentication Record, and also change the Listen Address in postgresql.conf. Details are [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/02/enable-remote-postgresql-connection/).

After I do these two things, my postgres service won't start. Here's my log:

```
2016-03-14 20:10:48 WET LOG:  invalid IP mask "trust": Unknown host
2016-03-14 20:10:48 WET CONTEXT:  line 81 of configuration file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/data/pg_hba.conf"
2016-03-14 20:10:48 WET FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
```

Line 81 is where I added my Client Authentication Record.

When I try to start the service, is it sufficient to use the Local System Account, or do I need to sign on? Do I need to configure something with group roles and login roles in the postgresql application? Finally, if it makes a difference, the db is hosted on a Google Compute Engine instance.

Comment: I think you'll have to post the lines that you've added to pg_hba.conf. And possibly postgresql.conf also. Obfuscate anything that needs to be hidden, of course. It's complaining about your syntax or it could be a line endings issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error you receive it is clear that you made the change in postgresql.conf from:

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost'
```

to:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

correctly.

The issue then is within pg_hba.conf where you should have:

```
host    all         all         192.168.101.20/24    trust
```

are you sure you did not put something like:

```
host    all         all         192.168.101.20/trust
```

or

```
host    all         all         192.168.101.20/    trust
```

or

```
host    all         all         192.168.101.20    trust
```

24 is the IP mask, that is how much of the ip will be used as filter. A 24 mask means that any host with ip 192.168.101.xxx will be accepted. A 32 mask will restrict the access to a single ip.

It seems the system is saying that it finds trust as ip mask...

Regards

Comment: The Client Authentication Record I added to pg_hba.conf looked like the last one you have there. It had no IP mask. I added the IP mask and now I'm able to restart the service.

However the script I'm using to access the db remotely is still returning the same error, but that might be a separate issue.

Comment: @duuug I know your post is quite old but i'm facing the same problem. I changed the mask as it is said here but my script stills gives me the error. How did you solved it?